# UITableViewController won't refresh after selection -> return to table

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitableview

I'm using a Window Template with a Navigation Controller and standard a `UITableViewController`.
When a row is selected, new `UITableViewController` pops up, and when a row in that table is selected, a new view with a webpage pops up.

Now when I navigate through this, and return to the first `UITableViewController`, and select another row, I always see the values of the first row I selected.

So it won't refresh or get the new data or update the table I don't know. (2nd `UITableViewController` and 3rd view with webpage always has the same information on it).

Also I'm using `viewDidLoad` for doing everything, tried `viewDidAppear` as well but that didn't seem to work out as well..

Thx in advance

W

Comment: Seems like a problem in your tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath: method. How is information passed from your first tableview to the second?

Answer (score 0):

try this,

add following line(as first line) in your `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`

```
[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
```

thanks.